# Code generates three errors while compiling

Tags: c++

I was tasked to write a program to find the longest path from the source node. I used Dial's algorithm and I have received three errors. The first is `'this' cannot be used in a constant expression` on line 58 `list B[W * V + 1];` referring to the `V`. The second error is `expression did not evaluate to a constant`, calling the same line as before.
The third error is left of `'.push_back' must have class/struct/union` calling out line 60 `B[0].push_back(src)`;

I am still fairly new to C++, so any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
# define INF 0x3f3f3f3f
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node* left, *right;
};

struct Node* newNode(int key)
{
    struct Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

class Graph
{
    int V;

     list< pair<int, int> > *adj;

public:
    Graph(int V);

    void addEdge(int u, int v, int w);

    void longestPath(int s, int W);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list< pair<int, int> >[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w)
{
     If (v < V && w < V)
     {
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
     }
}

void Graph::longestPath(int src, int W)
{
    vector<pair<int, list<int>::iterator> > dist(V);

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    dist[i].first = INF;

    vector<list<int>> B(W * V + 1);

    B[0].push_back(src);
    dist[src].first = 0;

    int idx = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        while (B[idx].size() == 0 && idx < W*V)
            idx++;

        if (idx == W*V)
            break;

        int u = B[idx].front();
        B[idx].pop_front();

        for (auto i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
        {
            int v = (*i).first;
            int weight = (*i).second;

            int du = dist[u].first;
            int dv = dist[v].first;

            if (dv > du + weight)
            {
                if (dv != INF)
                     B[dv].erase(dist[v].second);

                dist[v].first = du + weight;
                dv = dist[v].first;

                B[dv].push_front(v);

                dist[v].second = B[dv].begin();

            }

        }
    }

    printf("Longest Distance from Source\n");
    for (int = 0; I < V; ++i)
        printf("%d        &d\n", i, dist[i].first);

}



int main()
{
    struct Node* root = newNode(27);
    root->left = newNode(14);
    root->left->left = newNode(10);
    root->left->right = newNode(19);
    root->right = newNode(35);
    root->right->left = newNode(31);
    root->right->right = newNode(42);

    int V = 7;
    Graph g(V);

    g.addEdge(27, 14, 7);
    g.addEdge(27, 35, 8);
    g.addEdge(14, 10, 1);
    g.addEdge(14, 19, 3);
    g.addEdge(35, 31, 4);
    g.addEdge(35, 42, 2);

      g.longestPath(0,8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added the recommended changes and changed a few things in the code. I edited the print statement to print all paths, and i realized i forgot to add the function call, so that's there now. It runs but i get unexpected errors. I edited the code above for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing out of bounds at:

```
void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w)
{
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
}
```

This will cause undefined behavior. But I am lucky enough to get a segfault.

You can add a boundary check to fix it:

```
if(v < V && w < V){
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
}
```

---

Your code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/orYSZ4) but has some serious warnings on gcc:

You don't need s semicolon here:

```
struct Node* newNode(int key)
{
    struct Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
};
 ^^^^
```

This is not a valid C++ code:

```
list<int> B[W * V + 1];
```

Unlike C, variable length array is not allowed in C++ and depending on the compile you may get an error or warning, as some compiler accept such array as an extension to C++ standard. This will make your code not portable.

you can change it to:

```
vector<list<int>> B(W * V + 1);
```

You can use a debugger for finding these in your code. [Live debug](https://onlinegdb.com/SJuW6Z98B)

Comment: That is a runtime error, the OP is asking about the compile time errors.

Answer (score 0):

For `list B[W * V + 1]` the length of the c style array is not defined by constants, so it results in a variable-length array. And variable-length arrays are a C99 feature and not valid in c++.

`list B[W * V + 1]` would only be valid if `W * V + 1` can always be evaluated at compile time.

That's what the first two errors are about. And the third error is a follow-up error because `B` is not valid, the `push_back` on it isn't either.

In c++ you want to avoid c style array anyway an use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead. You can't use `std::array` because `W * V + 1` are not constant. So you need to use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<list<int>> B(W * V + 1);
```